# Does embedding static resources in section header still work

Tags: apex, javascript, sidebar

I was trying to modify some styling in standard pagelayout. I know way back there was an hack where devs used to create static resource with JS in it and embed the JS in the section header of a standard pagelayout ( pretty much the same as hacking the sidebar). There is an accepted solution here too on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254137/unable-to-access-dom-elements-of-standard-page-from-jquery-in-inline-vf-page

Does this still work?

I tried this today and the section header name is taking the script tags too in it as below

[image]

Comment: Can you post your exact markup? Rather than a change in the page behavior, it could be a syntactic mistake. Also the contents of your static resource, and anything else relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope.

https://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_spring13_release_notes.pdf, page 88

HTML Markup Escaped in Page Layout Custom Section Names

> Critical Update for rendering custom section names on page layouts is
>   available in affected organizations. This update changes how custom
>   section names in page layouts are rendered, to escape HTML tags and
>   other markup. Prior to the Spring’13 release, custom section names in
>   page layouts weren’t escaped, allowing the use of HTML markup and
>   other tags. This wasn’t an intended feature, and the Escape Page
>   Layout Section Names update corrects this behavior. With this update,
>   tags in section names are escaped, and aren’t interpreted as markup in
>   the browser. For example, the left angle bracket character, “<” is
>   rendered as `&lt;` and displays as a visible “<” in the browser.
>
> This Critical Update only appears in existing organizations that have
>   markup in section names, whether for styling such as font size or
>   color, or to execute JavaScript. These section names need to be fixed.
>   To fix them, edit the section name in the Section Properties panel,
>   and remove all HTML and other markup.
>
> When you have modified any affected custom section names, you should
>   activate this Critical Update.

Comment: The Google-fu is strong with this one.

Comment: @DanielHoechst I knew it's Spring-related, took me a while because I kept searching for "section header" (same as in the question). Still - you were first :) Luckily I don't rely on this "feature" anymore but I can imagine it caused bit of panic and extra work at my old job. Eh. I think same trick can be still embedded into sidebar? Probably with small delay / onload / ondcocumentready if it'd refer to the DOM that doesn't exist yet...

Answer (score 2):

I'm nearly certain there was a recent critical update that came out that prevented html markup in labels. Unfortunately, my Google-fu has failed me and I can't find a link for corroboration.